# "Duplicate check constraint name" without duplicate

Tags: mysql, import, mariadb, constraints

I'm trying to import a big MySQL schema into an empty database.

I have this error :

```
ERROR 3822 (HY000) at line 2682: Duplicate check constraint name 'notifications_chk_1'.
```

But no constraint `notifications_chk_1` exists.

- Checked the empty database : it's 100% empty.
- Checked the mysql file : `notifications_chk_1` appears only once:

```sh
$ grep "notifications_chk_1" qs_remote_multi.sql 
  CONSTRAINT `notifications_chk_1` CHECK (json_valid(`related`))
```

- Checked the database after the error occurred, no existing `notifications_chk_1` :

```sql
MySQL [(none)]> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE "notif%";
Empty set (0.006 sec)
```

Mysqldump version (source): `MySQL dump 10.19  Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`

Mysql version (target): `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.32-MariaDB, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Any idea?

Comment: Fixed it my doing a MariaDB fresh install (erasing all data).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing a MariaDB fresh install (erasing all data).

Comment: You could accept your own answer to make it clear it's been solved 