# Cannot have the same CHECK contraint name among different databases

Tags: mysql, mariadb, constraints, check-constraints

I'm trying to import a big MySQL schema into an empty database.

I'm getting this error :

```
ERROR 3822 (HY000) at line 2682: Duplicate check constraint name 'notifications_chk_1'.
```

Fact is, I have another database (a kind of copy) which has, obviously, the same constraint.

```sql
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE "notif%";
```

=>

```
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA   CONSTRAINT_NAME TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  CONSTRAINT_TYPE ENFORCED
def oteam_test  notifications_chk_1 oteam_test  Notifications   CHECK   YES
```

I looks very strange - and very annoying - not to be able to have 2 look-alike databases side by side if any CHECK contraint is present.

Can anyone explain this? Is this a bug?

How can I make it work?

Mysqldump version (source): `MySQL dump 10.19  Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`

Mysql version (target): `mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for macos10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`

Thanks

Comment: I am confused you have two servers MariaDB and mysql and are trying to restore to MySQL?

Comment: MariaDB is on a remote server, Mysql on my local machine.

Comment: And actually it's worse, removing the second DB and its CHECK constraint... doesn't solve anything, same error without any reason.

Comment: What version are you using? With 8.0.27 I can set up two schemas and use the same names in the separate schemas.

Comment: I just tested on MySQL 8.0.27 and I can create identical tables with a check constraint of the same name if they are in different schemas. I tested with your query against information_schema, and it returns two rows with the same constraint name.

Comment: I tested MariaDB 10.3 ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=17bebc65d195fe16b6059e399ba4a53f)) and I confirm it allows two tables in the _same_ schema to have the same check constraint name. This is nonstandard, constraint names should be unique within a schema. This shows that MariaDB's implementation of check constraints is not the same as MySQL's implementation. It is likely that in your MariaDB instance, two tables have the same constraint name. I suggest you run your information-schema query against your remote MariaDB instance.

Comment: Please read comment below, the issue is bigger: in any case I can't create my CHECK constraint, even is no other CHECK constraint is present.

Comment: Did you run your information-schema query against your remote MariaDB instance?

Comment: @BillKarwin why would I? My dump file is ok

Comment: Because you want to find out if two tables in the MariaDB instance in the same schema have the same constraint name. If such tables are present, they can be dumped successfully, but they cannot be restored except to another MariaDB instance.

Comment: In general, you should not expect MariaDB and MySQL to be compatible. MariaDB forked in 2010, and both products have been adding features since then. There are many such features that are incompatible. They are now different products. You should make an effort to use the same product and same version on your local machine as the one you use on the remote instance, or else you will struggle with these incompatibilities.

Comment: @BillKarwin there would be several "notifications_chk_1" in the dump, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking you to check. Is there some reason you can't run the info-schema query against your remote MariaDB instance?

Comment: @BillKarwin ah yes sorry, I already checked that for another thread, it appears only once.

Comment: | def                | oteam_multi_dev   | notifications_chk_1 | oteam_multi_dev | Notifications | CHECK           |

1 row in set (0.034 sec)

Comment: Okay if that's true, then I can't explain the error you got. Perhaps your MySQL data dictionary got corrupted somehow, and it still thinks a constraint by that name exists even though you dropped it. You will either have to rename the constraint, or you could try reinitializing the InnoDB tablespaces. But you'd be better off switching to the same software that you use on the remote instance for other reasons.

Comment: @BillKarwin ok switched to the same MariaDB version. Same problem, I'm updating the question as the problem has changed.

Comment: I can't help think that you have overlooked something. But I don't know what.

Comment: @BillKarwin I moved the issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579680/duplicate-check-constraint-name-without-duplicate

(I created it before and it's closer to the actual issue)

Comment: Closing this one